# CSS hide top part of text

Tags: html, css

**I prefer CSS only solution; I can change HTML structure; Always only single line of text**

**TL;DR;**

How to hide top part of text instead of bottom:

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div>HOME</div>
```

**Full example**

I want to hide top of the text line so I can simulate transition effect:

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
div span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  height: 20px;
}
div .default {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
div .hover {
  height: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
div:hover .hover {
  height: 25px;
}
div:hover .default {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="default">HOME</span>
  <span class="hover">HOME</span>
</div>
```

As you can see in example `.hover` is currently sliding from bottom because text is hidden from bottom to top when height is reduced.

I want to hide text from top to bottom, so that it will look like same text is inverting it's color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved that by using absolute positioned element over origin item:

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
div span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  height: 20px;
}
div .default {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  /* ADDED */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div .hover {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
div:hover .default {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="default">HOME</span>
  <span class="hover">HOME</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you against if I use pseudo elements to do it ? I play with `bottom` height to make it appears from top to bottom with the text in `content` property.

```
div .default {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
div .default:after { content: "Home"; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 100%; right: 0; background: #000; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;}
div .default:hover:after { bottom: 0; }
```

> HTML

```
<div>
  <span class="default">HOME</span>
</div>
```

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/pgzL2c25/6/)

**Other solution keeping the structure and avoid text in content property**

```
<div>
  <span class="default">HOME</span>
  <span class="black">HOME</span>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
div .black { position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 100%; right: 0; background: #000; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;}
div .default:hover ~ .black { bottom: 0; }
```

[Fiddle with 2nd solution](https://jsfiddle.net/pgzL2c25/10/)

Comment: You make same result, just it's sliding from top. Also I can't write dynamic CSS for every menu item.

Comment: Awesome work.  Please can you explain how it's work. Its too much helpful to me. I really appreciate your work and knowledge. Thank You.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I was thinking you wanted to hide text from top to bottom, right ? 
@KalpeshRajai Thanks ! I add some explanation for the first solution, tell me if you want further informations.

Comment: Thanks man @VincentG. Can your provide me some links where I can learn some basic rules of the CSS. I have the vary basic knowledge of the CSS. I want to increase the my knowledge in CSS If you know some website to learn CSS from beginner to Expert level So please tell me I want to learn that. If you some books name so please provide me the name of its. Thank you.

Comment: @Justinas "Also I can't write dynamic CSS for every menu item." - [why not use data attribute in the `content` then?](https://jsfiddle.net/v6a673sv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Given your first example, this one hides top part of the text. Just play around with the line-height on your animation

Just add on your `div span` style:

```
line-height: 5px; /* play with the value till desired look is reached*/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0ydLg9h/

Comment: `line-height: 0px` does not hide text